# Interpolation Search with Strings

Tags: c

Hello im trying to do interpolation search with strings.My strings insight the array are like these 2014-02-13T23:50:00.

```
void SearchInterpolation(char *data[],float data2[],char *data3[],int data4[], int n, char searchKey[]){

    long long int position, low, high,ResultKey,ResultLow,ResultHigh;
    low = 0;
    high = n-1;
    ResultKey = SearchKey(searchKey); // ResultKey = searchKey but integer
    do{

        ResultLow = SearchKey(data[low]); // ResultLow = searchKey but integer
        ResultHigh =SearchKey(data[high]); // ResultHigh = searchKey but integer
        position =low + (ResultKey - ResultLow) * (high-low+1) / (ResultHigh - ResultLow);
        if(strcmp(data[position], searchKey) == 0)
           break;
        else if(strcmp(data[position], searchKey) > 0)
         high = position - 1;
        else
         low = position + 1;
    } while ((strcmp(searchKey, data[low])>0) && strcmp(searchKey, data[high]) < 0);
    if ((strcmp(searchKey,data[position]))==0)              //if string is found
          {
          printf("The temp you are looking is: %.2f \n",data2[position]);
          } 


    low = 0;
    high = n-1;
    do{

        ResultLow = SearchKey(data3[low]); // ResultLow = searchKey but integer
        ResultHigh =SearchKey(data3[high]); // ResultHigh = searchKey but integer
        position = (ResultKey - ResultLow) * (high-low+1) / (ResultHigh - ResultLow) + low;   
        if(strcmp(data3[position], searchKey) == 0)
         break;
        else if(strcmp(data3[position], searchKey) > 0)
         high = position - 1;
        else
         low = position + 1;
    } while ((strcmp(searchKey, data3[low])>0) && strcmp(searchKey, data3[high]) < 0);

    if ((strcmp(searchKey,data3[position]))==0)              //if string is found
          {
          printf("The hum you are looking is: %d \n",data4[position]);
          } 
    else 
          printf("SEARCH FAILED \n");
}
```

The function SearchKey takes the text and convert it to a long long int for example 2014-02-13T23:50:00 --> 20140213235000.

My problems are:

a)Does not work for every timestamp that is already included in the array

b)When i give something random for example a text like dasd123 the program does not says SearchFailed

Answer (score 0):

Hello Again after some hours i found the solution.If anyone is interested here is the solution

```
void SearchInterpolation(char *data[],float data2[],char *data3[],int data4[], int n, char searchKey[]){

    long long int ResultKey,ResultLow,ResultHigh;
    int position,low,high;
    low = 0;
    high = n-1;
    ResultLow = SearchKey(data[low]); // ResultLow = searchKey but integer
    ResultHigh =SearchKey(data[high]); // ResultHigh = searchKey but integer
    ResultKey = SearchKey(searchKey); // ResultKey = searchKey but integer
    if (ResultKey>=ResultLow && ResultKey<=ResultHigh){
    do{

        ResultLow = SearchKey(data[low]); // ResultLow = searchKey but integer
        ResultHigh =SearchKey(data[high]); // ResultHigh = searchKey but integer
        position =low + (ResultKey - ResultLow) * (high-low) / (ResultHigh - ResultLow);
        if(strcmp(data[position], searchKey) > 0)
         high = position - 1;
        else if(strcmp(data[position], searchKey) < 0)
         low = position + 1;
        else
            low = position;
    } while ((strcmp(searchKey, data[position])>0) && (strcmp(searchKey, data[high]) < 0) && (strcmp(data[position], searchKey) != 0));
    }
    if ((strcmp(searchKey,data[position]))==0)              //if string is found
          {
          printf("The temp you are looking is: %.2f \n",data2[position]);
          } 
    low = 0;
    high = n-1;
    ResultLow = SearchKey(data3[low]); // ResultLow = searchKey but integer
    ResultHigh =SearchKey(data3[high]); // ResultHigh = searchKey but integer
    if (ResultKey>=ResultLow && ResultKey<=ResultHigh){
    do{
        ResultLow = SearchKey(data3[low]); // ResultLow = searchKey but integer
        ResultHigh =SearchKey(data3[high]); // ResultHigh = searchKey but integer
        position = (ResultKey - ResultLow) * (high-low) / (ResultHigh - ResultLow) + low;   
        if(strcmp(data3[position], searchKey) > 0)
         high = position - 1;
        else if(strcmp(data3[position], searchKey) < 0)
         low = position + 1;
        else
            low=position;
    } while ((strcmp(searchKey, data3[position])>0) && (strcmp(searchKey, data3[high]) < 0) && (strcmp(data3[position], searchKey)!=0));

    if ((strcmp(searchKey,data3[position]))==0)              //if string is found
          {
          printf("The hum you are looking is: %d \n",data4[position]);
          } 
   }
   else 
          printf("SEARCH FAILED \n");
}
```